# OCaml: how to solve findlib warnings of multiple `cmi`s

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocamlfind

Now I try to write a compiler using `ocamlfind` and some packages, especially `ppx_sexp_conv` with `opam`.
Somehow dependencies of `ppx_sexp_conv` require `compiler-libs` so the compilation option `-I ~/.opam/VERSION/lib/compiler-libs` is added when compiling files by `ocamlfind ocamlc -package ppx_sexp_conv`.

The problem is, `compiler-libs` includes very common name files like `parsing.cmi`, `main.cmi`, `lexing.cmi`.
This make conflicts of `.cmi` files and make many noisy warnings as follows:

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlc  -package ppx_sexp_conv -c parser.mli
findlib: [WARNING] Interface main.cmi occurs in several directories: ., /home/nomaddo/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
findlib: [WARNING] Interface lexer.cmi occurs in several directories: ., /home/nomaddo/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
findlib: [WARNING] Interface topdirs.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/nomaddo/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs, /home/nomaddo/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml
findlib: [WARNING] Interface parser.cmi occurs in several directories: ., /home/nomaddo/.opam/4.02.3/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs
```

```

Note that `main.cmi`, `parsing.cmi`, `lexing.cmi` and `main.cmi` exist in the same directory.

I believe that such file names are common and everybody want to use.
My question is, how to quiet such noisy warnings.
Thanks to them, it is hard to find more important warnings and errors immediately...

My environment: ocaml 4.02.3 with opam 1.2.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to suppress those warnings is to set findlib environment variable `OCAMLFIND_IGNORE_DUPS_IN` to `/home/nomaddo/.opam/4.03.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs`.

Here is an example with OCaml 4.03.0 and ppx_sexp_conv version 113.33.01+4.03.

parser.mli:

```
type t = int [@@deriving sexp]
```

In shell, do the following

```
export OCAMLFIND_IGNORE_DUPS_IN=/home/nomaddo/.opam/4.03.0/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs

ocamlfind ocamlc  -package ppx_sexp_conv -dsource -c parser.mli
```

You can see the `.mli` is preprocessed and no extra warning is emitted.

Reference:

- [findlib man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/findlib.conf)
- [Mantis 6754](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6754)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have solved this problem!

Comment: To find this path in a script: `OCAMLFIND_IGNORE_DUPS_IN=\`ocamlc -where\`/compiler-libs`